# Unit Testing with jUnit and Mockito for External REST API calls

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am building unit tests in a Spring Boot Java application for a service class.

The service class makes an external call to a REST API service that return a JSON response.  I am mocking this call using Mockito.  I am hardcoding a JSON in the mockserver response.

Is this bad practice to have hardcoded JSONs in your unit tests?  If the JSON structure changes, then the test should fail is my reasoning.  Is there a better, best practice where to do this?

**Example Snippet below:**

*The actual code is functional, I just edited this snippet it for brevity to get the idea across, so post a comment if you see any errors:*

```
    public class UserServiceTest extends TestCase {

    private static final String MOCK_URL = "baseUrl";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USER_ID = "353";

    UserService classUnderTest;
    ResponseEntity<Customer> mockResponseEntity;
    MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
    @Mock
    RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        classUnderTest = new UserRestService();
        mockRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(mockRestTemplate);

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classUnderTest, "restTemplate",
                mockRestTemplate);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classUnderTest, "userSvcUrl",
                MOCK_URL);
    }

    public void testGetUserById() throws Exception {

        mockServer.expect(requestTo(MOCK_URL + "/Users/" + DEFAULT_USER_ID)).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withSuccess(
                        "{\n" +
                                "    \"UserCredentials\": {\n" +
                                "        \"Password\": \"\",\n" +
                                "        \"PasswordNeedsUpdate\": false,\n" +
                                "        \"Security\": [\n" +
                                "            {\n" +
                                "                \"Answer\": \"\",\n" +
                                "                \"Question\": \"Why did the bicycle fall over?\"\n" +
                                "            }\n" +
                                "        ]\n" +
                                "}"
                        , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));


        Customer customer = classUnderTest.getUserById(DEFAULT_USER_ID);

        mockServer.verify();
        assertNotNull(customer);
        assertEquals(DEFAULT_USER_ID, customer.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: JUnit tells me the setup method must be static. Where is the withSuccess() method defined?

Comment: Question - Does your classUnderTest expose /Users/ API OR does it call an external REST endpoint (/Users/) from an external service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am currently in the same boat as you and my reasoning was as follows:
Creating a dummy JSON-response is like mocking an object and controlling it using `Mockito.when`. You would need to change anything in the `when().thenReturn()` call when you changed some inner parsing or you expect different results. This is the same with a JSON-response where calls are changed and object representations are altered.

Therefore my guess would be that this is fine. Reading various articles about testing REST API's, the general concensus is that creating dummy JSON-responses is good practice. Best practice would be to (from time to time) download the real JSON-response and insert this as the mocked response. This way you can keep your tests up-to-date with the external party, while the tests can run without internet requests.

Edit as requested:

- Ruby - [Stubbing external services](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests),
- Python - [Testing a successful call](http://engineroom.trackmaven.com/blog/real-life-mocking/)
- JavaScript - [An example of AJAX testing](http://appendto.com/2010/07/mock-your-ajax-requests-with-mockjax-for-rapid-development/)
- Python - [Lastly a Google tutorial about mocking](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/mocks)

Comment: Hey Tim would you mind editing your post with some of the sources you used just for reference?

Comment: Hello Anataliocs, I have added some of the references I found. Hope they help you =]

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much.  That gives me a lot more confidence in my approach, since bad unit tests are almost worst than no tests they say ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to shine a light on another approach to consider, and that is to create POJO (e.g. data model, JavBean) of the object that the JSON represents then using a JSON serializer, like Gson from Google, to convert it to a JSON String.

```
UserCredentials uc = new UserCredentials ();
//set the values
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(uc);
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that.  I like that approach a lot.  Thanks for the input.